# Where is rails_helper.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am currently following this [tutorial](http://twinkalsavani.com/?p=135) to begin testing rspec with capybara and selenium. I included the necessary gems and ran a *bundle install*, but cant seem to find the *rails_helper.rb* to continue with the tutorial.

This is on rails 4.2.4.

Thanks,
Otterman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rails_helper.rb` in generated when you run `rails g rspec:install`. Make sure you are using a relatively recent version of `rspec-rails` as versions before 3.0 only the `spec_helper.rb` is used configure the test suite (well by default at least).

The `spec_helper.rb` file is used to set up RSpec itself and `rails_helper.rb` sets up the rails stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the file in `../spec/rails_helper`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I was missing

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

in my gemfile.

After which I ran

```
rails generate rspec:install
```